# Calendar's last column is over flowing in lightning-input type=date LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, date-picker, community-cloud

I have a lightning web component added on a Visualforce page in community through aura dependency app. My component is inheriting styling from Visualforce page which is causing several problems. One of them is when using 'lightning-input type=date', the calendar's last column is overflowing. Screenshot:

[image: Calendar]

Is there a way that we can turn off the styling coming from Visualforce page in LWC?